# Compare Get metadata activity with lookup output

Tags: azure-data-factory

I was trying to do a delta load using ADF. I have a get meta data activity on my blob location to read all the files using getchildItem and lookup activity which reads loaded file names from a sql table. Following this I have a filter activity which should filter out the new files from the blob location.
[image: ADF pipeline]

expression on items

```
@activity('GetRawFilenames').output.childItems
```

expression on Condition

```
@not(contains(activity('GetLoadedFilesList').output.value,item().name))
```

But still its not filtering out the file list in the filter output. Could the experts please help? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63906910/filter-lookup-results-from-values-in-second-lookup-in-azure-data-factory). They describe same problem. Expression on condition should be:

`@not(contains(join(activity('GetLoadedFilesList').output.value,','),item().name))`

so after joining of GetLoadedFilesList activity your code should be working